# How to solve 'VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)' error on Virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Oracle VirtualBox v5.2.18 on my Windows 10 1803 and ran Ubuntu 18.04 on it, but it gave me this message: "VT-x is not available" (see image below):

[image: VT-x is not available]

VT-x is available on the CPU I'm using and is enabled in BIOS, also I've turned off Hyper-V using task manager.

What should I do next?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Virtual Box. After trying to solve the problem for a  while I decided to try VMWare Player. This also gave me an error, something with Device Guard being enabled. Then after some searching I came across this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIBdY-5zr58

In short my problem was solved after entering the commands below in a administrator command prompt:

```
bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader
```

Then copy paste the rest below and press enter

```
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Now, Restart your system

Both VMWare and Virtual box started working after the reboot on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Uncheck Hyper-V via Control Panel/ Windows features on or off (reboot maschine)
- Switch off Memory Integrity in Windows Defender Security Center / Equipment Safety (? translated by myself...)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it fixed by disabling Containers and Hyper-V features from Windows Features dialog
[Windows Features Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN0Tq.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have uninstalled hyperv and ensured SVM, vt-x or whatever virtualization is available in your bios, then try this:
Run these commands in an elevated cmd prompt, then reboot

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

FTR I do not recommend disabling windows defender integrity features.

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty frustrated on Windows 11 having the similar issue, I spent like 5 hours on this and suddently I stumbled on Core Isolation feature (searchable in taskbar) - I DISABLED this function and suddenly BOOM! VT-x works again, I hope this helps someone